# JsViews - Binding 'change' event to <select> fails

Tags: events, jsviews

I have this drop down:

```
                <select id="selectCard" class="form-control" data-link="SelectedCardType">
                    <option value="-">- Select -</option>
                    {^{for CardTypes}}
                    <option data-link="value{:Item1} {:Item2} selected{:Item1 == ~root.SelectedCardType}"></option>
                    {{/for}}
                </select>
```

And do this:

```
                $.templates("#spTmp").link("#SelectionPanel", viewModel)
                    .on('change', "#selectCard", function () {
                        UpdateGrid();
                    });
```

However, when I get into function UpdateGrid() the value of `SelectedCardType` is the old one (it's not updated yet).
What am I supposed to do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! Got it!
This seems to be a JQuery problem.
I observe the viewModel instead...:

```
$.observe(viewModel, "SelectedCardType", UpdateGrid);
```